# Field renormalization of $\phi^4$ to second order

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, 1pi-effective-action

In Peskin & Schroeder Problem 10.3 pg. 345 they renormalize the field in $\phi^4$ theory using the following 2-loop sunset diagram.

[image]

When looking at the correlation function $G^{(2)}_0$ this would seem the obvious thing to do since:

$$G_0^{(2)}=\frac{1}{p^2+m_0^2}-\frac{\lambda_0}{(p^2+m_0^2)^2}\int \frac{d^Dk}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{1}{k^2+m_0^2}$$ $$+\frac{\lambda_0^2}{3!(p^2+m_0^2)^2}\int \frac{d^Dk_1}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dk_2}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{1}{(k_1^2+m_0^2)(k_2^2+m_0^2)((p-k_1-k_2)^2+m_0^2)}+\cdots
$$

where for ease of notation let me write:

$$G_0^{(2)}=\frac{1}{p^2+m_0^2}-\frac{\lambda_0}{(p^2+m_0^2)^2}I_1+\frac{\lambda_0^2}{3!(p^2+m_0^2)^2}I_2+\cdots
$$

But as far as I am aware it is not this that we renormalize but the vertex function $\Gamma_0^{(2)}$ which is given by:

$$\Gamma_0^{(2)}=\frac{1}{G_0^{(2)}}$$
$$=(p^2+m_0^2)+\lambda_0I_1-\frac{\lambda_0^2}{3!}I_2+\frac{\lambda_0^2}{p^2+m^2}I_1^2+\cdots$$

thus should the $I_1^2$ term not be included in the field renormalization and why is it often omitted?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question. Have a look to my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/375360/ (the second part). It may be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will drop the subscripts $0$ and superscript $(2)$ for ease of notation. If you are going to compute $\frac{1}{G}$ up to second order in $\lambda$, you better make sure that you have at your disposal an expression for $G$ which is complete up to second order. Yours is not. You are missing a $\lambda^2$ term which basically is $I_1^2$ with three free propagators. The $I_1^2$ term in $\Gamma$ is just not there. It is cancelled by the term you missed in $G$. Also note that even if it was there for some weird reason it would not contribute to the wave function/field strength renormalization. The latter is obtained from the $p^2$ coefficient of the Taylor expansion around zero external momentum. Since $I_1$ is an "infinite constant", it has no dependence in the external momentum $p$ and so no $p^2$ term. The first graph which contributes a $p^2$ term is the sunshine graph $I_2$.

Comment: If the diagram you are talking about is the one I am thinking of then it is not 1PI and as such should not be included in $\Gamma$ which is calculated using only 1PI diagrams.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification: If you read my answer carefully you will realize that my point is: the graph $I_1^2$ which is not 1PI but still connected, should be included in $G$ which you forgot to do. If you did, then you would not see it appear in $1/G$ which is $\Gamma$ that should only have 1PIs in it.

Comment: The lecture notes I am using give $\Gamma^{(N)}$ as (in general): $$\Gamma^{(N)}_0=\left. \left[ \left( \prod^N_{j=1}\tilde G_0^{(2)}(p_j)^{-1} \right) \tilde G_0^{(N)}(p_1,\ldots, p_N)\right] \right|_{1PI}$$
It seems like you are saying it is actually given by: 
$$\Gamma^{(N)}_0=\left( \prod^N_{j=1}\tilde G_0^{(2)}(p_j)^{-1} \right) \left. \left[ \tilde G_0^{(N)}(p_1,\ldots, p_N)\right] \right|_{1PI}$$ or even $$\Gamma^{(N)}_0=\left( \prod^N_{j=1}\tilde G_0^{(2)}(p_j)^{-1} \right)  \tilde G_0^{(N)}(p_1,\ldots, p_N)$$  
is this correct?

Comment: where $\left.\left[ \ldots \right] \right|_{1PI}$ means we only consider the 1PI diagrams for everything in the square brackets (e.g. $\tilde G_0^{(2)}$ in the first case would only being evaluated to include 1PI.

Comment: I can write a thoughtful answer about the precise definitions of vertex functions and the Legendre transform vs 1PI. But it would have to be an answer to a new post about that (unless someone already asked) and I can't do that right at the moment. My answer was entirely based on how you phrased your question. I was only talking about $N=2$ and I used the definition that you wrote above, i.e., $\Gamma:=1/G$. Since there is still some communication problem that prevents you from seeing that my answer does indeed settle your question, let me try the Socratic method and ask you questions...

Comment: ...Do you agree that your expansion up to second order of $G_{0}^{(2)}$ is incorrect? (yes or no)

Comment: Ok I found this PDF (http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/kleiner_reb8/psfiles/04.pdf) which clears up my lack of knowledge about vertex function definitions. Thanks for your answer.